# Custom Filter in Angular throws in console errors

Tags: angularjs

Getting started with Angular . Had a doubt . In this piece of code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: totalMoney">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country +', '}} {{x.salary | currency}} {{', '}} {{x.salary + x.bonus | currency}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway',salary:8500,bonus:350},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden',salary:5500,bonus:250},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England',salary:7250,bonus:750},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway',salary:4750,bonus:220},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark',salary:5950,bonus:250},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden',salary:11050,bonus:550},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark',salary:6700,bonus:300},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England',salary:3500,bonus:150},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway',salary:9750,bonus:400}
        ];

})
.filter('totalMoney',function(){
    return function(user) {
        return user.salary + user.bonus;
    }
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`the totalMoney filter does not work as expected and throws errors in console`.

But the following code works .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: totalMoney">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country +', '}} {{x.salary | currency}} {{', '}} {{x.salary + x.bonus | currency}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway',salary:8500,bonus:350},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden',salary:5500,bonus:250},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England',salary:7250,bonus:750},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway',salary:4750,bonus:220},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark',salary:5950,bonus:250},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden',salary:11050,bonus:550},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark',salary:6700,bonus:300},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England',salary:3500,bonus:150},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway',salary:9750,bonus:400}
        ];
     $scope.totalMoney = function(user) {
        return user.salary + user.bonus;
     }
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But is not the `first approach` the desired one while creating custom filters ?

Then why did not it work ? 
How to make it work ?

Comment: You do not need a filter. You are just orderingBy value

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Actually the orderBy filter can take as a parameter not only a string but also a function. so when u declare as function it works. But when u create custom filter you are actually creating a custom orderBy filter which u cant assign to orderBy. you have use as orderBy instead of passing custom filter to existing filter

Comment: filter are defined by | thiskeyword anything after that will be filter,orderBy: totalMoney  you are giving a parameter to a filter (orderBy)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign custom filter to a filter like

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: orderByValue">
```

`orderBy` Can only take sting and function as parameter not other custom filter. Either you can create a function and pass to `orderBy` like in you did in your working example. Or you can use custom filter as i have shown below.

This will be your custom filter:

```
myApp.filter('orderByValue', function () {
  // custom value function for sorting
  function myValueFunction(card) {
    return user.salary + user.bonus;
  }
```

This will be your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderByValue">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country +', '}} {{x.salary | currency}} {{', '}} {{x.salary + x.bonus | currency}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy will not allow objects. so you have to create custom filter.

View code: 
`<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderObjectBy">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country +', '}} {{x.salary | currency}} {{','}} {{x.salary + x.bonus | currency}}
  </li>
</ul>`

JS code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway',salary:8500,bonus:350},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden',salary:5500,bonus:250},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England',salary:7250,bonus:750},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway',salary:4750,bonus:220},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark',salary:5950,bonus:250},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden',salary:11050,bonus:550},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark',salary:6700,bonus:300},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England',salary:3500,bonus:150},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway',salary:9750,bonus:400}
        ];

})
.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });

    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a['salary']+a['bonus'] > b['salary']+b['bonus'] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
};
});
```